# Wordpress Comment Display Modification

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble with modifying the way comments are displayed.

Currently they are always displayed as "Comments (%)". Changing the code that's displaying the comments to  doesn't seem to do anything.

Where can I properly change the way # of comments are displayed?

I'm using the primepress theme - http://www.techtrot.com/primepress/

Blog link - http://stringo0.teamjl.net

My goal is adding a comment bubble displaying the number of comments - any easier way to do this is appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need to know about what's available in showing comment meta: [Template Tags/comments popup link « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comments_popup_link)

Comment: Thanks - using the format specified there doesn't seem to be working to change things - it still displays Comments (%).

Comment: This works for me: `<?php comments_number('Comments(0)', 'Comments(1)', 'Comments(%)'); ?>`

Comment: The problem I'm having is no longer what I pass into the function, the text output always turns out to be "Comments (%)".

Comment: Disable the plugin WP Recent Comments; it might be conflicting. Then ask in the theme's support forum.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up using another function, get_comments_number() instead - not sure what was messing with the other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with that particular theme, but in some there are multiple references to the comment functions, depending on the context (eg display single post, multiple posts, search results, page, etc). So check all the php files for references to the comment functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the comments_number and related popup function didn't work for me. I think it's because of some filters interfering, not sure which ones - could be the intense debate commenting plugin, because I noticed that it redirects to a different anchor (#idc...).

I ended up using another function, called get_comments_number which I found by looking into the wp source code.